How to make a double loop to evaluate this triple integral
I have a function f(t1,t2,t3, a,k) where I make a triple integral over t1,t2,t3 and make a loop on the value of the variable "k".

The integration limits of t1 and t2 are from "0" to "a"

The integration limits of t3 is from 0 to "infinity"


The question is how to make a second loop over the variable "a" where it tends to zero.
Here is the code that I use:
import numpy as np
import scipy.special
from scipy import integrate
from scipy.special import kn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
import time, sys

H = 4.10061*10**-5
ti = -100*H
end = -H
step = H
a=0

f = lambda t1, t2, t3, k: t1 + t2 +k + a + t3
X = np.arange(0, 50, 0.1)

g = float('inf')

def F(x):
    res = np.zeros_like(x)
    for i, val in enumerate(x):
        y, err = integrate.tplquad(f, 0, a, lambda x: 0, lambda x: a, lambda x, y: 0, lambda x, y: g, args=(val,))
        res[i] = y/(math.exp(H*a)**2)
    return res

plt.plot(X, F(X))
plt.title("P(k)")
plt.show()

As you glance that in this code I write f(t1,t2,t3,k) and let a=0. But that makes the integral vanish.
So how to adjust this code and write f(t1,t2,t3,a,k) then run a second loop on "a" as a variable like "k" such that "a" tends to zero.

Why can you not write for a in ...:?

@mkrieger1. Hey, I’m a beginner in python, so if you please declare your reply.
