How to make a double array from two lists using np.zeros
I have these two lists:
X=np.arange(0,50,0.1)
Y=np.arange(10,20,1)
How to generate a doubles array from these two lists by np.zeros_like()
Then how to make a counter on this array using enumerate()
I tired something like:

import numpy as np

import scipy.special

from scipy import integrate

from scipy.special import kn

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import math

import time, sys

from itertools import count



X=np.arange(0,50,0.1)

Y=np.arange(10,20,1)



res = np.zeros_like((x, y))

for i, (va, val) in enumerate(zip(va, val))

y= va+val

res[i]=y

return res


But it gives an error: UnboundLocalError: local variable ‘y’ referenced before assignment
Any help is appreciated!

You need declare what y is in np.zeros_like((x, y)).

Please [edit] and fix your code to include a [mre]. In your question, both indentation and syntax are broken. Thank you.


X and Y are NumPy "arrays", not Python "lists". 2) Python is case sensitive. Rename your arrays x and y to instead of X and Y to follow the usual conventions, and this will fix the UnboundLocalError. 3) What do you hope for np.zeros_like((x, y)) to produce? That function is for creating an array of zeros with the same shape and type as a single input array, but you are giving it a tuple of two arrays of different shapes.


What would be the shape of this array? Are you trying to reproduce meshgrid?

Hi, thanks for the answer. The res that i have mentioned here is an example, what I'm really trying to do is an integral over a function then make two loops on the values of two variables. Kindly look at this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78435857/how-to-make-a-double-loop-to-evaluate-this-triple-integral?noredirect=1#comment138280911_78435857. @MattHaberland
